# Many to many relationship join table only updating first time

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I have relationships as defined in the diagram shown here.

- A set of TestCustomers in the TestCustomer table
- A set of TestContacts in the TestContact table

Links between `TestCustomers` and `TestContacts` are stored in the `TestCustomerContact` table:

[image]

In terms of the domain, Customers can have Contacts, Suppliers can have Contacts and several other entities can have Contacts.

Instead of duplicating the `Contacts` table and having a `<Parent>Contact` table for each parent with 1:N relationships, I have opted to have one `Contact` table with N:N links between the `Contact` and its parent element (`Customer` as an example). Other reason is that `Contacts` have other relations too.

In terms of the UX you add a Contact as a child of the parent. I.e. you add a new Contact in the context of a Customer. I.e. you view the Contacts for the Customer and then add one. However in the background, the code needs to add the Contact as well as the CustomerContact entry and make the correct links.

The EF Core objects are shown below

`TestCustomer` has a collection of `TestContacts`:

```
public class TestCustomer
{
    public TestCustomer(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    protected TestCustomer()
    {}

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TestContact> Contacts { get; } = new List<TestContact>();

    public void AddContact(TestContact contact)
    {
        Contacts.Add(contact);
    }
}
```

`TestContact` has a collection of `TestCustomers` because that is how it is implemented in the database, deviating slightly from the domain rules, but the domain classes will implement the rules.

```
public class TestContact
{
    public TestContact(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    protected TestContact()
    {}

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TestCustomer> Customers { get; set; } = new List<TestCustomer>();
}
```

`TestCustomerContact` is the join object:

```
public class TestCustomerContact
{
    protected TestCustomerContact()
    {}

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long TestCustomerId { get; set; }
    public long TestContactId { get; set; }
}
```

The model is declared like this:

```
public static ModelBuilder BuildTestCustomer(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<TestCustomer>().HasKey(p => p.Id);

  modelBuilder.Entity<TestCustomer>().Property(p => p.Id).IsRequired();
  modelBuilder.Entity<TestCustomer>().Property(p => p.Name).IsRequired();

  modelBuilder.Entity<TestCustomer>()
    .HasMany(p => p.Contacts)
    .WithMany(t => t.Customers)
    .UsingEntity<TestCustomerContact>(
      j => j.HasOne<TestContact>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(p => p.TestContactId),
      j => j.HasOne<TestCustomer>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(p => p.TestCustomerId));

  modelBuilder.Entity<TestCustomer>()
    .Navigation(p => p.Contacts)
    .UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Property);

  return modelBuilder;
}

public static ModelBuilder BuildTestContact(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<TestContact>().HasKey(p => p.Id);

  modelBuilder.Entity<TestContact>().Property(p => p.Id).IsRequired();
  modelBuilder.Entity<TestContact>().Property(p => p.Name).IsRequired();

  modelBuilder.Entity<TestContact>()
    .Navigation(p => p.Customers)
    .UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Property);

  return modelBuilder;
}
```

The code I use to test this is as follows

```
public async Task Run()
{
  long customerId = await AddCustomer("Customer");

  await AddContact(customerId, "Peter Contact");
  await AddContact(customerId, "John Contact");
  await AddContact(customerId, "Tom Contact");
  await AddContact(customerId, "Harry Contact");
}

private async Task<long> AddCustomer(string customerName)
{
  // AddCustomer runs in a request thus has its own DbContext
  dbContext = new TestDbContext();

  // Add a Customer and commit
  TestCustomer customer = new TestCustomer("Customer");
  dbContext.Add(customer);
  await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

  await dbContext.DisposeAsync();

  return customer.Id;
}

private async Task AddContact(long customerId, string contactName)
{
  // AddContact runs in a request thus has its own DbContext
  dbContext = new TestDbContext();

  // Fetch Customer
  TestCustomer customer = dbContext.Find<TestCustomer>(customerId);

  // Create a new Contact
  TestContact contact = new TestContact(contactName);

  // Add the Contact to the Customer
  customer.AddContact(contact);

  // Commit to DB
  await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

  await dbContext.DisposeAsync();
}
```

However only the first TestCustomerContact entry has the correct TestContactId. The rest still have temp values.

[image]

If I change

```
 TestContact contact = new TestContact(contactName);
```

to

```
  TestContact contact = new TestContact(contactName);
  dbContext.Add(contact);
  await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

it works correctly, but I want both inserts to happen in one transaction.

Not sure why this is?

Comment: Side note: You should add a foreign key in the database so at least you don't end up in such an inconsistent situation in the database (you will get an exception on `SaveChanges()` instead).

Comment: The size of number is wrong.  You must be mixing long, int, int16.  The wrong numbers are just negative because the size is not consistent.  Check the database to see the size defined in the tables.   The database looks like it is using BigInt.

Comment: @jdweng As usual, a long-shot comment showing that you don't pay attention. All Id properties are `long`, all Id columns are `bigint`.

Comment: Which EF version is this? I can't reproduce the issue using EFC6 and Sql Server. It's strange that the table doesn't seem to have foreign keys, a created model from code does have them.

Comment: Try changing this: `TestCustomer customer = dbContext.Find<TestCustomer>(customerId);` to this: `TestCustomer customer = dbContext.TestCustomers.Include(x => x.TestContacts).Single(customerId);`

Normally this wouldn't be necessary/advisable if just adding one relative though, but something to try. This would just ensure the proxy is initialized. Additionally, things like assigning a temporary ID should not be necessary when working with entities as EF will be expecting to set identity columns and their associated FKs automatically on save. That may be closer to the actual issue.

Comment: @GertArnold :   A BigInt is not a long.  Read my comment again.  What I said was correct.

Comment: @jdweng Bigint is the equivalent of .Net's long in SQL Server.

Comment: @Gert Arnold : I bigInt and L:ong are not exactly the same and depending on the driver the conversion may cause issues.  In this case it is obvious that the differences are causing a positive number to become negative.

Comment: @jdweng The output screenshot show that this is SQL Server. There have never been issues like that in EF with SQL Server. My main point is that before making any comments it would be helpful to reproduce the issue and see if it really produces what you suspect. By not doing that you only add confusion.

Comment: @GertArnold : This is a typical error when you mixed types.  You are creating the confusion.  This is basic two's compliment when you use the wrong sizes.  It is basic computer mathematics.

Comment: *when you mixed types* Which is not what happens here.

Comment: @jdweng  long is the same as bigint. I use long through the classes and bigint for all PKs. This is not a conversion error because the rest of the system works perfectly. Also the first insert also works perfectly.

Comment: @GertArnold correct there is no mixing types i consistently use long<->bigint throughout

Comment: @GertArnold This is EFC6 (.NET6) & Sql2016. I understood there is no need to define the FK in the DB because I am using Fluent to define the model. I will try adding FK to DB. The weird thing is that the first one works

Comment: @StevePy yes I dont set any IDs. I let EF do that

Comment: @GertArnold defining the FKs in the DB causes the inserts to fail as expected because the join table FKs not updating. looks like EFCore is not handling this

Comment: @GertArnold I shared a link to the project to reproduce here: https://pastebin.pl/view/bf75a307

Comment: Inside the `AddContact(long customerId, string contactName)` method, you are constantly creating new instances: `dbContext = new TestDbContext()`. Unsurprisingly, there is no information about relationships in them.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I create new instances of DbContext specifically to simulate the new instances of DbContext that will be created with each HTTP request. There is one request/DbContext instance to add a Customer. And then another request/DbContext instance to create the Contact.

Comment: Is the problem solved? / The `TestCustomerContact` join entity should have a composite primary key `modelBuilder.Entity<TestCustomerContact>().HasKey(x => new { x.TestCustomerId, x.TestContactId });`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov no not yet solved. I will try your suggestion tx

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov your suggestion works perfectly. Thanks very much! Do you know why would one need a composite key in this situation whereas other N:N one can have a 'normal' Id as PK? You are welcome to post your answer as the solution.